# Community Flow and Languages

Tags: community, visual-workflow, language

We have a simple community and a flow inside in English. What we need to do is to translate both of them to another language.

Translating the community itself is fine since there are language choices for communities. But how can I translate the flow inside of the community? Do I just recreate this flow with another language? This doesn't feel correct. If yes then how can the user see the flow language change when the standard language selector is changed?

What is the approach with languages and flows in communities?

Comment: I haven't tried this, so I don't know if it works for flows in communities, but you can translate flows using the translation workbench: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workbench_flow_components.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've decided on using a custom language seletor. Simple En, Es that will take me to a copy of the same community page in another language. Flows and it's screens can be easily copied and translated if you edit the flow to be available as template. The picklists can be translated using [translation workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workbench_flow_components.htm&type=5).